# how to use javascript onclick event handler for same class of anchor elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my javascript:

Here i grab data using ajax get request and call this function:

```
function fetch_user_data(data) {

    $(user_board['results']).each(function(attributes,value){

        $('.main_container').append(
            '<div class="pin" id='+attributes+'>\
                <div class="holder">\
                    <a class="image" href="" title="Photo number 1" pin_id='+ attributes +'>\
                        <img src="'+ value['profile'] + '" />\
                    </a>\
                <p class="desc">' + value['name'] + '</p>\
                <ul id="pin_actions">\
                    <li id="awe"><a href="#" onClick="onTabAction('+value['user_id']+'); return false;"></a></li>\
                    <li id="cof"><a href="#" onClick="onTabAction('+value['user_id']+'); return false;" ></a></li>\
                    <li id="ban"><a href="#" onClick="onTabAction('+value['user_id']+'); return false;" ></a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>'
        );

    });
}

function onTabAction(id,action) {

    console.log(id);
    console.log(action);

}
```

Here is a problem, my data contains 33 objects, and then according to object there are 33 html boxes belong to person profile. I attached **onclick event handler** in **anchor** tag and get user id through custom function which is **onTabAction**. Along with id i want to get a string like: `onTabAction('+value['user_id']+',actionstr)` but when i call this function and print output in console.log: it prints user id once and string equal to object quantiy like **li#actionstr**. In short I would like to get both string and id and make an url to query on other url. Please help me on this stuff, also if i get string and id i have to remove that anchor from main page as i place that anchor on other page.

Comment: $(user_board['results']).each suggest it runs multiple times but you give the li elements and id, if this happens more than once then there are multiple elements with the same id, in html an id has to be unique for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, with the code you posted I can't make a working example because most of it is missing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
.clickable{
  cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var someData=["one","two","three"],
    i=0,
    user_id="my user id",
    $main=$('.main_container');
    for(i=0;i<someData.length;i++){
        $main.append(
                "<h1>"+someData[i]+"</h1>\
                <ul id=\"pin_actions\">\
                    <li class=\"clickable\" data-action='awe'>awe</li>\
                    <li class=\"clickable\" data-action='cof'>cof</li>\
                    <li class=\"clickable\" data-action='ban'>ban</li>\
                </ul>"
        );
    }
    $main.attr("data-userID",user_id);
    //attach onclick
    $('.main_container').find("li").on("click",onTabAction);
});
function onTabAction(e) {
    console.log("userID:",this.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute("data-userID"));
    console.log("action:",this.getAttribute("data-action"));
}
</script>
</head>
 <body>
   <div class="main_container">
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: action is a string which i have to set statically in function so if a user click on first link then he gets "awe", on second gets "cof" as you can see in li id's, so how would i get these strings

Comment: and data-userID='"+value['user_id']+"' is not works, first " is not working and second if i click on single anchor then i get all id's means equal to object count

Comment: Changed the code, didn't test it but I think you should get the idea of adding strings to elements using the data-attribute.

Comment: I didn't understand what is going there, if i attached onclick in li then it works and get back to me only single id but for string what should i do